# Avoiding dot in true single-character middle name (abbrv-style)

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

One of my co-author's name has the pattern "Aaaa B Ccccc", where (due to transcription from Chinese) the "B" is indeed a single character (part of the given name). Now BibTeX (in `abbrv`-style) likes to render this as `A. B. Ccccc` (note the dot trailing the "B"), whereas I'd either like `A. Ccccc` or `A. B Cccccc`. I tried `Aaaa~B` or `B\`, but still no go. Any tips?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is really a nasty trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\onelettername}[1]{#1\aftergroup\@gobble}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
author={Truman, Harry {\onelettername{S}}},
title={A title},
journal={J. Nice Results},
year=2012,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{key}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A fabulous trick!

Comment: Nice solution for numeric citations. It blows up for `alpha` (it creates a lower-case `o`), but I rarely use that one. Thanks!

Comment: @ShiDoiSi In case the bib style doesn't make abbreviations, just say `\newcommand{\onelettername}[1]{#1}`, so that you can still use the same `.bib` file.